# OpenLayesr map 4 Panning/Dragging is not working in C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, openstreetmap, openlayers, panning

I am developing a desktop project using Visual Studio and C# and I have an Open Street Map in my application. Everything is working good expect panning with mouse. I search a lot on Google and stack-overflow but no success, that is why I decided to ask here.

Note: 
1)If I run same HTML file in browser(Chrome, IE-11) everything is working fine.

2)If I use keyboard arrow then also panning is working fine.

3)Zooming have no issue.

4)Panning through code is working fine, like I want to move to any city or country. It is also working fine(center: panLocation).

5)Same code I have for browser application and desktop application.

6)Just issue is panning map with mouse in desktop application.

If anything not clear please ask me in comment. Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally findout the solution. Might it will help someone in future.
Just add compatible meta tag in your html file-

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE =10,9,8,7">
```